# How to create a prompt with Perl::tk

Tags: perl, user-interface, tk-toolkit

There is lots of tk stuff out there, but none of it seems to so exactly what I want it to do... CreateOk below will create a message box(without another main window) and return the result upon pressing ok. I would like to create a box that behaves like the ok box, but prompts the user for text input and returns the text upon clicking a submit button. I have also posted my attempt below.

```
sub CreateOk
{
   my ($statement, $title) = @_;
   my $return;

   if (defined($statement))
   {
      my $main_window = MainWindow->new();
      $main_window->withdraw();

      $return = $main_window->messageBox(
         -title   => $title // 'Ok pop-up',
         -message => $statement,
         -type    => 'OK',
         -icon    => 'question',
      );
   }
   else
   {
      cluck "No message given for OK pop-up!";
   }

   return($return);
}
```

And this is my attempt

```
sub CreatePrompt
{
   my ($question, $title) = @_;
   my $pop_up;

   if (defined($question))
   {
      my $main_window = MainWindow->new();

      my $winMain = MainWindow->new(
         -title => $title // 'User Input',
      );
      $winMain->Label(
         -text => $question
      )->pack( -side => 'left' );

      my $entName = $winMain->Entry(
         -textvariable => \$pop_up
      );
      $entName->pack( -side => 'left' );
      $winMain->Button(
         -text    => 'Show',
         -command => sub{ close; }
      )->pack( -side => 'left' );

      MainLoop();
   }
}
```

But this will create the main window and the popup, how do I just create the popup like before?

Comment: Why do you create `$main_window` at all if you're not using it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the MessageBox and DialogBox?

https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Tk/pod/messageBox.pod

https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Tk/pod/DialogBox.pod

Comment: messageBox has no way of getting user input and DialogBox seems to open the mainwindow too